# Generated Excel file showing date value differently in different systems ( Asp.net web application)

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, excel

I have asp.net web application, which sends email to users with .xls attachment, this file has few columns which displays date, so when users are downloading this excel file in there systems, only users whose system setting is in the format of dd-mm-yyyy the date is appearing correctly, to all the other users whose system setting is not in dd-mm-yyyy format it is not appearing properly the date column in not proper.

Any idea how this can be fixed, the requirement is to make the date column appear in dd-mm-yyyy format irrespective of users time setting

I am using the below lines of code to send the .xls file through email

```
 using (StreamReader stRDR = new StreamReader(Server.MapPath("~/2.1.3.2-B-MAILER.html")))
                {
                    sHTMLbody = stRDR.ReadToEnd();
                    sHTMLbody = sHTMLbody.Replace("{NAME}", sSalesL2name.ToString());
                    sHTMLbody = sHTMLbody.Replace("{MESSAGEBODY}", sMsgBodyTemplate);
                }
                var dtServer = DateTime.Now;
                string FileName = "SalesL2_" + sSalesL2sapcode + ".xls";
                String sPath = Path.GetTempPath() + FileName;
                //String sPath = Path.GetTempPath() + sL3sapcode.ToString() + dtServer.ToString("_yyyy-MM-dd__HH-mm-ss") + ".xls";
                FileInfo FI = new FileInfo(sPath);
                StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
                HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWriter);
                // For the below line to work, we need [override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm as part of class]
                GridView gvTemp = new GridView();
                gvTemp.AllowPaging = false;
                gvTemp.DataSource = dtResult;
                gvTemp.DataBind();
                gvTemp.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
                gvTemp = null;
                System.IO.StreamWriter vw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(sPath, true);
                stringWriter.ToString().Normalize();
                vw.Write(stringWriter.ToString());
                vw.Flush();
                vw.Close();
                Attachment attXLS = new Attachment(FI.FullName);
                //"application/vnd.ms-excel";
                // Send Email
                // Create new Mail Object
                objMail = new MailMessage(); // Create new Mail Object
                objMail.From = new MailAddress("ersdocumenttracking@hcl.com");

**Stored proc**
select distinct t1.[Project code],t1.[Project Description],t1.[Start Date],
t1.[End Date],t1.[Customer],t1.[Customer Name],t1.[Customer Group],
[AM Sales SAPID],[AM Sales Name],[L3 Sales SAPID],[L3 Sales Name],[L2 sales SAPID],[L2 sales Name],
t1.[Proj Category Description],t1.[DU Desc (L4)],t1.[SDU Name (L3)],
t1.[PM Code],t1.[PM Name],t1.[VBDU Desc (L2)],t1.[SPM Code],t1.[SPM Name],t1.[DUH Code],t1.[DUH Name],
t1.[SDUH Code],t1.[SDUH Name],[VBDUH Code],[VBDUH Name],[Geo Reg Name],[Customer SOW],t1.[MSA],
[MSA Start Date],[MSA End Date],[SOW Start Date],[SOW End Date],[Document applicability],
[Avg Rev based on AMJ '18 PP (in $K)] [Avg Rev based on last quarter PP (in $K)],[UAR $K],
[MSA RAG check],[SOW RAG check],
[PONumber],[POValidFrom],[POValidTo],[Balance in $K],
[PO RAG check],[PO Insufficient flag],[MSA Documents remarks], [SOW Documents remarks],
[PO Documents remarks] 
from [tbl_MSA_SOW] as t1 left join [tbl_PO] as t2 
on t1.[Project code] = t2.[Project Code]
inner join [tbl_Sales_mapping] as t3 
on t1.[Project code]=t3.[Project code] 
where (t1.[MSA RAG check]=@RagValue or t1.[SOW RAG check]=@RagValue
or t2.[PO RAG check]=@RagValue) 
and t3.[L2 sales SAPID]=@sapid and t3.[AM Sales Name] !='-'
```

Comment: Start using a specialized library for creating Excel files, like [EPPlus](https://github.com/JanKallman/EPPlus). All you are doing now is creating a HTML page with an .xls extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be doing this. If you are sending an excel sheet, dates should be displayed to the user as such. Let excel display the date according to the user's system settings. Do not preset the format. If you do, then the user gets the dates as strings and will have to convert them in order to do anything useful with the data.
As a further point, is there any reason, why you are sending xls instead of xlsx? Given that this is going via email, users will be much happier downloading xlsx files as they are guaranteed not to contain macros. Xls are considered more dangerous and many email clients prevent the user from opening xls, exactly for this reason.

EDIT

Having seen your code, I understand the problem more clearly.  What you are producing is not a true Excel spreadsheet; it is simply a text file to which you have added a .xls extension.

To understand the difference, create a new Excel spreadsheet, enter some sample data, and then save it as xls (Excel 97 format).  Now open the file in Notepad and see what you get.  Now open the file you are generating through your code.

What is happening here?  Excel is clever enough to recognise that, although your generated file has the wrong extension (ie the contents of the file are not what is required for xls), it has data that it can display in a spreadsheet, and so conveniently loads it.

Changing your extension to xlsx does not help.

You have two options: 1) be honest and use an extension appropriate to the format of your generated file (*.txt, *.csv etc) or 2)
you need to generate the Excel workbook as a native Excel file.

If you choose the latter route there are various options: 1) use the Office interoperability libraries, 2) use third party Excel libraries (some of which are free - please Google c# Excel library) or 3) produce your own library.  I personally had to go for 3) as the problem with 1) is that Office needs to be installed on the web server and with 2) it either costs money or it means using free software, that my employer is generally unhappy to do.

If you want to do 3) I can give you some help.  The first step that I recommend, is to create a sample xlsx file in Excel and save it.  Then change the extension in Explorer to .zip (yes!!) and extract.  Then examine the contents.  You will find it interesting, but that is what you will need to create.  It is not easy, but can be done using inbuilt functions in .Net.

EDIT 2)

If you choose to go down the csv route (and I am not sure that what you have here really is csv, you need to open the generated file to be sure), then it will currently only work correctly for systems with dd-mm-yyyy date formats.  To make it work for any locale, you need the date to be in ISO 8601 format (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd).  To do this you have two choices. Firstly, alter your stored procedure to format the date when generating the data, thus:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(10), your_date, 126) AS your_date FROM your_table;
```

(Note that you should supply an alias for the output column, otherwise it gets Expr1 etc).
Secondly, you could add a DataColumn to the DataTable after retrieving the data, step through the rows of your DataTable and assign the new column with ISO 8601 formatted version of the pre-existing date column, and then delete the pre-existing date column.  Do all this before you generate the text output.

Comment: ok Jonathan got your point, you mean to say that according to the users ssytem setting the date column will appear, yes if it appears properly thats fine, but here in our case for the users with other than dd-mm-yyyy its not appearing properly i mean the date column, and as you said donot present the format, so what exactly i need to remove in the code can you help me

Comment: You have not shown any code where you are creating the spreadsheet, only the code where you create the file name. Also please take my point about xlsx into account. SO is not a free coding site. We are here to help, but not to write your code for you. Please look at the guide to asking questions.

Comment: Yes Jonathan, thank you I understand that, the data in the excel file is getting generated from stored procedure which has columns start date and end date and datatype used for those columns are Datetime.

Comment: Okay Jonathan thanks for your detailed analysis on the above issue, i will look into it and will let you know if i require any help, thanks once again for your time.

Comment: Hi Jonathan,one doubt here, so if i change the extension to .csv in the code, will the datetime column will display the date correctly in any system irrespective of the time format in there system.

Comment: Please see my new edit.  Also please note that I am now off to a football tournament, so will not be able to respond for some time.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, added my stored procedure in the question, in the stored proc there are few columns which are displaying date, example: startdate , enddate columns display date in excel file, can you tell how should i change the startdate column, so that it will display date correctly  in any system irrespective of system setting. thanks

Comment: `CONVERT(varchar(10), t1.[Start Date], 126) AS [Start Date]`

Comment: thank you Jonathan that helped, its working fine locally, i will check in production server and update you, thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: My pleasure. If all is well, please remember to accept the answer. It helps other people with similar problems.

Comment: Hi Jonathan it worked in production, once again thanks a lot for your time

Comment: Hi Jonathan, bimistake i clicked on answer was not usefull, please dont mind, I again clicked on the correct arrow, which shows answer was usefull, but can you help me where exactly i need to accept the answer, is it just the arrow or is there anything else i need to do. let me know thanks

Comment: You need to click on the tick next to the answer.  Irritatingly this is grey, which most new users assume means greyed out (iei not available).  This is a quirk of SO.  You can in fact click it, and then it gets filled in.